# Change input text on radio button selection different forms

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I am trying to make the input text change when pressing on radio button

the form it self have 5 option with multiple radio buttons and input text

the input text that i am trying to change is in different form since also when changing the input text in the main form it should change it on the other one

i get this for now

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
 $("input[type=radio]").click(function () {
   $(this).closest('form').find("input[type=text]").val(this.value);
});
});
```

but this change the input text in the current form

how can i make to change the second form input text

```html
main form
<form action="cart.php" name="cart" id="cart" target="cart"
method="post" onsubmit="return cart();">



<input name="selector0" type="hidden" value="A">
<input name="selector0hyphen" type="hidden" value="-">

<div class="selector">
    <div class="selector">
      ccc
    </div>
    <p>
      <label>
      <input name="selector1" type="radio" id="selector1_0" value="J" checked="checked">
      TYPE : p </label>
      <br>
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="selector1" value="K" id="selector1_1">
        TYPE : l </label>
        </p>
    <div class="selector">j</div>
    
    <p>
      <label>
      <input name="selector2" type="radio" id="selector2_0" value="G" checked="checked">
        aaa</label>
      <br>
      <label>
      <input type="radio" name="selector2" value="U" id="selector2_1">
        u</label>
    </p>
    <input name="selector2hyphen" type="hidden" value="-">
    <div class="selector">bbb</div>
    <p>
      <label><input name="selector3" type="text" id="selector3" value="000" size="5" maxlength="3">
    inches. Please use 3 digit</label></p>
        <input name="selector3hyphen" type="hidden" value="-">

<div class="selector">      wd</div>
    <p>
      <label>
      <input name="selector4" type="radio" id="selector4_0" value="S" checked="checked">
24</label>
      <br>
      <label>
      <input type="radio" name="selector4" value="X" id="selector4_1">
22</label>
      <br>
      <label>
      <input type="radio" name="selector4" value="F" id="selector4_2">
21</label>
      <br>
      <label>
      <input type="radio" name="selector4" value="T" id="selector4_3">
211</label>
    </p>
    <div class="selector">t Type</div>
    <p>
      <label>
      <input name="selector5" type="radio" id="selector5_0" value="1" checked="checked">
33</label>
      <br>
      <label>
      <input type="radio" name="selector5" value="2" id="selector5_1">
3"</label>
      <br>
      <label>
      <input type="radio" name="selector5" value="3" id="selector5_2">
st m</label>
      <br>
      <label>
      <input type="radio" name="selector5" value="4" id="selector5_3">
st</label>
      <br>
      <label>
      <input type="radio" name="selector5" value="5" id="selector5_4">
mm</label>
      <br>
      <label>
      <input type="radio" name="selector5" value="6" id="selector5_5">
mmmf</label>
    </p>
    <div class="selector">acc</div>
    <p>
      <label>
      <input name="selector6" type="radio" id="selector6_0" value="A" checked="checked">
None</label>
      <br>
      <label>
      <input type="radio" name="selector6" value="B" id="selector6_1">
b</label>
      <br>
      <label>
      <input type="radio" name="selector6" value="C" id="selector6_2">
bb</label>
      <br>
      <br>
    </p>
    <p>
<input name="" type="image" value="submit" src="/images/raq.png" style="margin-left:18px;">
 </p>
    
      </div>
      

second form where input should change


<tbody>
   <tr>

          <th>Model </th>
        <td style="width:100%;">
A<input name="selector1" type="text" value="_"   maxlength="3">
<input name="selector2" type="text" value="_"  maxlength="3">
<input name="selector3" type="text" value="000"  maxlength="3">
<input name="selector4" type="text" value="_" maxlength="3">
<input name="selector5" type="text" value="_"  maxlength="3">
<input name="selector6" type="text" value="_"  maxlength="3">

</td></tr>




     </tbody>
```

so for now if i press on radio button it change the input in the same form

i need to change the input text on the second form

for example i press on type p it change the first input text in the second form

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Problem in your code:

`find("input[type=text]").val(this.value);` will give you all the input type=text, and update all of them with `this.value`, what you really want is to target the specific element, so should be something like `.find("input[name=" + this.name + "][type=text]")`

#### Solution:

Use `.find("input[name=" + this.name + "][type=text]")` to **find the last element with name="xxxx" and type=text, this will return only one result since the combination is unique**

The idea is to target the single input element you want to update, also you should clean up your code, attribute orders etc, remove id if you are not using it.

UPDATE: change input update radio button.

`.find("input[type=radio][name=" + this.name + "][value=" + this.value + "]")`

when update your text input, you can target the input where `type=radio` with `same name` and `same value` then use `.prop("checked", true)` to check it.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("input[type=radio]").click(function() {
    $(this).closest('body').find("input[name=" + this.name + "][type=text]").val(this.value);
  });

  $("input[type=text]").on('input', function() {
    $(this).closest('body').find("input[type=radio][name=" + this.name + "][value=" + this.value + "]").prop("checked", true);
  });

  //init
  $("input[type=radio]:checked").click();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
main form

<div class="selector">
  <div class="selector">
    ccc
  </div>
  <p>
    <label>
      <input name="selector1" type="radio" id="selector1_0" value="J" checked="checked">
      TYPE : p </label>
    <br>
    <label>
        <input type="radio" name="selector1" value="K" id="selector1_1">
        TYPE : l </label>
  </p>
  <div class="selector">j</div>

  <p>
    <label>
      <input name="selector2" type="radio" id="selector2_0" value="G" checked="checked">
        aaa</label>
    <br>
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="selector2" value="U" id="selector2_1">
        u</label>
  </p>
  <input name="selector2hyphen" type="hidden" value="-">
  <div class="selector">bbb</div>
  <p>
    <label><input name="selector3" type="text" id="selector3" value="000" size="5" maxlength="3">
    inches. Please use 3 digit</label></p>
  <input name="selector3hyphen" type="hidden" value="-">

  <div class="selector-column-boxhead"> wd</div>
  <p>
    <label>
      <input name="selector4" type="radio" id="selector4_0" value="S" checked="checked">
24</label>
    <br>
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="selector4" value="X" id="selector4_1">
22</label>
    <br>
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="selector4" value="F" id="selector4_2">
21</label>
    <br>
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="selector4" value="T" id="selector4_3">
211</label>
  </p>
  <div class="selector-column-boxhead">t Type</div>
  <p>
    <label>
      <input name="selector5" type="radio" id="selector5_0" value="1" checked="checked">
33</label>
    <br>
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="selector5" value="2" id="selector5_1">
3"</label>
    <br>
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="selector5" value="3" id="selector5_2">
st m</label>
    <br>
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="selector5" value="4" id="selector5_3">
st</label>
    <br>
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="selector5" value="5" id="selector5_4">
mm</label>
    <br>
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="selector5" value="6" id="selector5_5">
mmmf</label>
  </p>
  <div class="selector-column-boxhead">acc</div>
  <p>
    <label>
      <input name="selector6" type="radio" id="selector6_0" value="A" checked="checked">
None</label>
    <br>
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="selector6" value="B" id="selector6_1">
b</label>
    <br>
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="selector6" value="C" id="selector6_2">
bb</label>
    <br>
    <br>
  </p>
  <p>
    <input name="" type="image" value="submit" src="/images/raq.png" style="margin-left:18px;">
  </p>

</div>


second form where input should change


<tbody>
  <tr>

    <th>Model </th>
    <td style="width:100%;">
      A<input name="selector1" type="text" value="_" maxlength="3">
      <input name="selector2" type="text" value="_" maxlength="3">
      <input name="selector3" type="text" value="000" maxlength="3">
      <input name="selector4" type="text" value="_" maxlength="3">
      <input name="selector5" type="text" value="_" maxlength="3">
      <input name="selector6" type="text" value="_" maxlength="3">

    </td>
  </tr>




</tbody>
```

Comment: @jodo glad to help

Comment: is it possible to reverse it ? if i change the input text on the second form it will change the radio button ? thank you

Comment: thanks again, i am stuck with the input text "selector3" it change when i change in main form but not able to change when i change second form http://jsfiddle.net/8duvf6we/

Comment: @jodo http://jsfiddle.net/f9buw34e/, with `$(this).closest('body').find("input[type=text][name=" + this.name + "]").val(this.value);`

Answer (score 1):

The form your changing the input is the first form,
select the next form by adding the next method after ( closest( form) )
Don't Forget form tags plus they have to be next to one another.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("input[type=radio]").click(function () {
    $(this).closest('form').next() .find("input[type=text]").val(this.value);
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

$(this).closest() is used to find the closest parent element. It would only select the element that is the parent of $(this) element.

You should give the text inputs unique IDs so that they can be easily identified.

Change this-

```
<input name="selector1" type="text" value="_"   maxlength="3">
```

To this-

```
<input name="selector1" id="selector1" type="text" value="_"   maxlength="3">
```

And then in jquery,

```
$("input[type=radio]").click(function () {
    $("#selector1").val(this.value);
});
```

Comment: tried that i added for example selector2 to the second option but when i press on 1 of the radio button option it change both input http://jsfiddle.net/rc2uzfge/ .. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Create a `onchange` function for all the radio button on all the forms. Pass the value of the radio button on the function and get the value from the function.

Eg:

```
Function myChange(myRadioVal)
{
$("#inputTextBoxId").val(myRadioVal);
 //code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Try this code

Add a common class to every radio button

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.class_name_of_radio').change(function() {
        $("input[type=text][name="+this.name+"]").val(this.value);
    });
});
```